# Odoo: how to add third party libraries

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-website

I I host odoo on server . when i add third party library in html editor file 'web_common_assets' it give error "some modules are not working". Because of this i cannot open html editor to revert code and also cannot access website setting. thanks in advance

Error

```
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortable' of undefined
(index):81 979
(index):135 1903
(index):144 1269.063125px
(index):153 495.96937499999996px
web.assets_common.js:2523 error: Some modules could not be started 
Failed modules:          Array\[1\] 
Non loaded modules:      Array\[22\]window.odoo.log @ web.assets_common.js:2523
http://45.79.217.173:8069/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)][1]
```

Comment: which type of code add in html editor?

Comment: that was cdn link of velocityjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "html editor" select "Main Layout" and do in head tag this type of code it worked.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.js"></script>
</head>
```